# sqlite3: How to check whether a given column exists?

Tags: sqlite

In sqlite3 this command gives you a list of all columns for a table:

```
PRAGMA table_info('table_name');
```

How can one check for just a specific column in that table?

I tried these commands, without success:

```
PRAGMA table_info('table_name') WHERE name = 'column_name';
SELECT * FROM (PRAGMA table_info('table_name')) WHERE name = 'column_name';
```

The desired result is (any) output when the column is present and no output when it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's not the desired output, but perhaps this simple approach may help you:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name LIMIT 0
```

Afterwards check the error code of sqlite3.

Comment: I used a similar approach as a workaround, but I want to avoid producing errors when there is no real error. - Otherwise it gets convoluted.